# How to generate observe block

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to generate the observe block like so:

```
        created: function () {
            var viewData = {
                type: 'Pikachu',
                name: 'Gary'
            };

            // iterate over view data
            for (prop in viewData) {
                //set the property
                this[prop] = viewData[prop];


                var handlerName = 'update' + prop

                // set add the property to the observe block
                this.observe[prop] = handlerName;

                // set the handler
                this[handlerName] = function (valueWas, valueIs) {
                    console.log('you have changed ' + prop + ' to ' valueIs);
                };
            }
        },
```

Is this possible?

This is being completely unresponsive for me, no errors, but the handler isn't being called.

Comment: I couldn't get dynamic `propertyChanged` handlers cooking either: http://jsbin.com/hojiwajo/1/edit

I suspect what's happening is that Polymer's internals need the `observe` block and `Changed` handler information upfront in order to create a mapping from property to handler. But in theory, I feel like this should work. Would you mind filing a bug (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/new)?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I figured that Polymer would need the observe block upfront. I've filed the issue (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/448).

Comment: Oh yeah, we should stop calling this the `observe block` because it annoys JavaScript language lawyers. It's actually an `object`. A `block` is a code construct (which also uses `{ }`, fwiw).

This whole thing is probably my fault for calling it a `block` in the first place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some arcana. Before finalizing the prototype the `polymer-element` code explodes the `observe` map into parallel arrays as a (highly annoying) speed optimization.

You can re-optimize your instance by calling:

`this.element.optimizePropertyMaps(this);`

Where `this.element` refers to the `polymer-element` that defined the current element type (fwiw, it's known that `element` is a bad name for this property).

Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/tahixumu/4/edit

Also for performance, Polymer considers the observers and other special lists to be features of a shared prototype. Since your dynamic data is presumably *per-instance* I had to make your example more complicated for a proper test.

Keep an eye out, there may be other complications due to subverting Polymer's per-prototype expectations.