# How can I dynamically register new attributes in Polymer when a component is ready?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

**Question**

How can I dynamically register new attributes in a web component once it is ready?

**Problem**

Let's suppose that we have one naive web component like the following [1]:

```
<polymer-element name="wc-bridge">
  <script>
    Polymer ('wc-bridge', {
      publish: {
        x: 0
      },
      observe: {
        x: 'xfn'
      },
      created: function () {
        this.publish.y=0;
        this.observe.y='yfn';
      },  
      xfn: function (ov, nv) {
        console.log ({key:'x', old: ov, new: nv});
      },
      yfn: function (ov, nv) {
        console.log ({key:'y', old: ov, new: nv});
      },
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[1]. http://jsbin.com/yakisayiwi/1

As it can be seen, `x` is an attribute bound to `xfn` handler at design time. I also want to bind a fresh attribute `y` later on when the component is ready. I have tried to do that in the more natural way that I thought of by enriching both the `publish` and `observe` objects but my approach doesn't work. I suppose this is because I am late on the digesting process with that objects. So, is there any way to solve this problem?

**Context**

I do realize that my aim is a bit odd, but there is a why. I am trying to make a bridging component that fires an event when a generic attribute is changed where both the event name and the attribute are given at configuration time. Here is a simple use case:

```
<wc-bridge x="{{v}}" y="{{v}}"> <!-- x & y are unknown at design time -->
  <wc-bridge-event on="x" fire="e1"/> <!-- x & e1 are known by digesting this -->
  <wc-bridge-event on="y" fire="e2"/> <!-- y & e2 are known by digesting this -->
</wc-bridge>
```

**Unanswered related questions**

http://goo.gl/xzKPKw

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432998/how-to-generate-observe-block/22600107#22600107 help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric. It seems what I was looking for. I have tried to adapt that code but I have detected a twofold problem related to lifecycle. It is explained on the code here [ http://jsbin.com/juvomalavi/1/edit ]. Could you please take a glance to it?

Comment: Polymer is designed to carefully optimize bindings/observations on prototypes, so that you can make a lot of elements that operate efficiently. Trying to use that same system for dynamic, per-instance behaviors is going to give you a hard time. You said "that fires an event when a generic attribute is changed": this is easy, you can implement `attributeChanged` yourself and fire matching events with `fire`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. Up to my knowledge what you suggest in your comment is exactly what I am trying to do here [ jsbin.com/juvomalavi/1/edit ] but I don´t get any behavior. Could you please, take a glance to my code and let me know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can because attributes are loaded only once time.

If I need to do that I manage with only one attribute that contains a map, {key:value}, as value instead a primitive like string. Then observe the attribute and apply logic to know how do with new values.

Hope this is useful

Comment: Thanks a lot @aqquadro but as you can check in the context your solution is not valid for me.